# GCC can not resolve method call with defaulted parameter and following parameter pack

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++17

Is GCC allowed to reject the following code due to ambiguity? To me it looks like a bug.
It compiles fine with msvc, clang and icc.

See here: https://godbolt.org/z/9fsnhx

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void Foo(int={}){
        std::cout << "A";
    }

    template<
        typename... T
        ,typename... Args
    >
    void Foo(int={}, Args&&... args)
    {    
        std::cout << "B";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.Foo<int>();
}
```

Comment: gcc the rejects `a.Foo<int>();`, all the others are ok, clang rejects `a.Foo<int>(3, 4);` all the others are ok with that one. I personally don't even understand what this should mean and why this is even expected to be compiled at all.

Comment: I compile this code with gcc in MacOS, and outputs A. This is the command I compiled this code. ```
# compile gcc t.cpp -std=c++17 -lstdc++
# run ./a.out
# outputs A ```

Comment: Ah, right. The clang bug with `a.Foo<int>(3, 4);` seems to be fixed in clang trunk.

Comment: The parameter pack overload is usally a tie breaker. If there is a call without a parameter pack this one should be selected (informally)

Comment: The rule that may make the first `Foo` a best match is https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.partial#11. But I am not sure the intent was to make it applies here. GCC applies this rule only if the default function argument is not used: https://godbolt.org/z/sqscGo

Comment: The issue with MSVC is a known bug. Godbolt assumes `output = warning`.
See here: https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/1034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a gcc bug. As [Oliv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63390165/gcc-can-not-resolve-method-call-with-defaulted-parameter-and-following-parameter#comment112090588_63390165) notes in the comments, if you provide an argument for the defaulted parameter, gcc accepts - but this should be irrelevant in this case.

The relevant rules to point out here are [[temp.deduct.partial]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.partial), paragraph 3:

> The types used to determine the ordering depend on the context in which the partial ordering is done:
>
> - In the context of a function call, the types used are those function parameter types for which the function call has arguments.<sup>138</sup>

(the footnote says):

> Default arguments are not considered to be arguments in this context; they only become arguments after a function has been selected.

Paragraph 11:

> If, after considering the above, function template F is at least as specialized as function template G and vice-versa, and if G has a trailing function parameter pack for which F does not have a corresponding parameter, and if F does not have a trailing function parameter pack, then F is more specialized than G.

Paragraph 12:

> In most cases, deduction fails if not all template parameters have values, but for partial ordering purposes a template parameter may remain without a value provided it is not used in the types being used for partial ordering. [ *Note*: A template parameter used in a non-deduced context is considered used. — *end note* ] [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> template <class T> T f(int);            // #1
> template <class T, class U> T f(U);     // #2
> void g() {
>   f<int>(1);                            // calls #1
> }
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

In short, when considering partial ordering here:

1. The default argument doesn't matter, we just consider the two function templates taking an `int` as their first parameter.
2. The `T` in the first overload and `T...` in the second overload *also* don't matter. They're *not* in the set of types used for partial ordering, they're not arguments to the function. This is similar to the example in paragraph 12, where the template parameter also named `T` also does not play a role.

So basically we're ordering between:

```
void Foo(int);
template <typename... Args> void Foo(int, Args&&...);
```

which is a very straightforward case where the first is more specialized. gcc gets this wrong - I submitted [96602](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96602).